# Join Arrays (per row) using Standard SQL in BigQuery

Tags: sql, arrays, user-defined-functions, google-bigquery

I have a table which contains a single column with rows

table_1.row_a:
    "ABC"
    "DEF"
    "GHI"

And a javascript UDF function which takes a row as input and outputs an array of Strings for each row.

```
splitStrings(table_1.row_a)

["A", "B", "C"]
["D", "E", "F"]
["G", "H", "I"]
```

How can I join these results to get the desired output table:

```
A
B
C
D
E
F..
```

So far I have the following code:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION splitStrings(str STRING)
RETURNS ARRAY<STRING>
LANGUAGE js AS """

return str.split();

""";

SELECT * FROM UNNEST(["ABCD", "EFGH", "IJKL", "MNOP"]) AS words
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(splitStrings(words))
```

However the result is:

```
-WORDS-   f0_
ABCD .    ABCD
EFGH .    EFGH
IJKL .    IJKL
MNOP .    MNOP
```

And i would like a single letter per row
A
B
C..

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use `union all`?

```
select col1 from t union all
select col2 from t union all
select col3 from t;
```

Or if you really want to use arrays, a UDF is unnecessary:

```
select val
from (select 'A' as a, 'B' as b, 'C' as c union all
      select 'D', 'E', 'F' union all
      select 'G', 'H', 'I'
     ) x cross join
     unnest(array[a, b, c]) val;
```

As for your approach, I think you want:

```
SELECT val
FROM table_1 CROSS JOIN
     UNNEST(splitStrings(table_1.row_a)) val;
```

That is, select the result from the `UNNEST()`.

Comment: I have updated my code to show the result of a cross join which is not what I would like. I do need to use a UDF, this is a simplified example. I am not sure how to use a union all. There is only one column and thousands of rows. Not col1, col2, col3..

Comment: @user759885 . . . Thee is no reason to reinvent the wheel, but the third query does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Below example for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT "ABC" word UNION ALL
  SELECT "DEF" UNION ALL
  SELECT "GHI" 
)
SELECT value
FROM `project.dataset.table`, UNNEST(SPLIT(word, '')) value
```

with result:

```
Row value    
1   A    
2   B    
3   C    
4   D    
5   E    
6   F    
7   G    
8   H    
9   I
```